# jQuery mobile: Wait until $.getJSON is finished

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, asynchronous, jquery-callback

I want to populate a table with `$.getJSON` call:

```
$.getJSON("localhost/url",
function (data) {
    $.each(data.reporting_list.reporting, function (i, item) {
        rows = '<tr><td>' + item.data1 + '</td><td>' + item.data2 + '</td></tr>'
    });
    $('#aaa').append(rows);
});
```

After populating I want to fire some page changes:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#homePage");
```

But the page changes before `$.getJSON` completes.
I want to change the page only after `$.getJSON` is complete and show ajaxloader instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do

```
$.getJSON("localhost/url", function (data) {
    $.each(data.reporting_list.reporting, function (i, item) {
        rows = '<tr><td>' + item.data1 + '</td><td>' + item.data2 + '</td></tr>'
    });
    $('#aaa').append(rows);
    //move to the page in the callback itself
    $.mobile.changePage("#homePage");    
});
```

Comment: Exactly what you want I hope

Answer (score 4):

Although the answer is already given by [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny), But I just wanted to make it more clear, the proper usage of `$.get()` method in jQuery

According to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jQuery-get1 The `$.get()` method is actually

```
jQuery.get( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

Where The two blocks i.e. `data` and `success` will only called when the request is completed, so you can call this function `$.mobile.changePage("#homePage");` in either of the block

i.e. in the `function (data) {  }` block, like [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) suggested or you can call it in any of the other callbacks below.

```
var jqxhr = $.get("example.php", function() {
  alert("success");
})
.done(function() { alert("second success"); })
.fail(function() { alert("error"); })
.always(function() { alert("finished"); });
```

Like `$.ajax()` the above callbacks work as `success` `error` and `complete` respectively

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
ajaxcall(function(){ $.mobile.changePage("#homePage");});

function ajaxcall(callback){
$.getJSON("localhost/url", function (data) {
    $.each(data.reporting_list.reporting, function (i, item) {
        rows = '<tr><td>' + item.data1 + '</td><td>' + item.data2 + '</td></tr>'
    });
    $('#aaa').append(rows);
    //move to the page in the callback itself
    callback();
});
```

Using callback function also, you can also try this way